# scroll down icon in center of page doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a portfolio / landing page with a scroll down icon / link in center of page; however, the effect when the page scrolls down is not working as intended. if I click on any link on the top navbar I get the scroll up effect I want. If someone can point out what I'm missing. This was done using bootstrap framework. here's the link to the page
http://techgeorge.org/
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="portfolio, projects, Information Technology, Web Development, Android Development">
    <meta name="author" content="George Louis">

    <title>Techgeorge - This is my portfolio. A list of some of my projects. Web Development, and Android Development</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                    <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>  <span class="light">Tech</span>George
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#myCarousel">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#map">Map</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Intro Header -->
    <header class="intro">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2 id="sub-heading"><span class="light">Tech</span>George</h2>

                <img src="img/mypic.png" class="mypic" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100">
                <p>Here you'll find a list of my projects!</a>
                </p>
                <ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pctechtips25/" target="_blank" class="btn facebook btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Facebook</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://github.com/zentech" target="_blank" class="btn github btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Github</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOH7oeWBE2pgcFPFmj7lCqw" target="_blank" class="btn youtube btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-youtube left fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Youtube</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- scroll down button  -->
                <a href="#myCarousel" class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>


      <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <br>
      <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Page Header -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">My Projects
                    <small>Web Development & Android Applications</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <a href="http://pctechtips.org/sohotech" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/sohotechnology.png" alt=""></a>
                </a>
                <a href="#"><h3>sohotech</h3></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <a href="http://techgeorge.org" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/techgeorge.org.png" alt=""></a>
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">techgeorge</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <a href="http://pctechtips.org/apps/calculator" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/calculator.png" alt=""></a>
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Web Calculator</a>
                </h3>
              </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                    <a href="http://pctechtips.org/apps/simon" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/simon-game.png" alt=""></a>
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Simon Game</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <a href="http://pctechtips.org/apps/clock" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/clock.png" alt=""></a>
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Pomodoro Clock</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <a href="http://pctechtips.org/apps/tictactoe" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/tictactoe.png" alt=""></a>
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="http://pctechtips.org/apps/tictactoe" target="_blank">Tic Tac Toe</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f0ENrRU16bQ" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/netDroid.png" alt=""></a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pctechtips.netdroid&hl=en" target="_blank">Android: Netdroid</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <a href="https://github.com/zentech/JLanScan" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/jlanscan.png" alt=""></a>
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">JLanScan</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <a href="http://pctechtips.org/apps/wiki" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/wiki-search.png" alt=""></a>
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="http://pctechtips.org/apps/wiki" target="_blank">Wiki Search</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <hr>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div><!-- /.carousel -->

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <img src="img/me.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
                <p>My name is George and I'm a long time IT and Developer who venture in many areas of Information Technology. I am a <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/zentech/front-end-certification" target="_blank">certified Front End Web Developer</a> from freecodecamp.org. And I hold several certification from Microsoft. I spend my days developing apps, making youtube video tutorials <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOH7oeWBE2pgcFPFmj7lCqw"> youtube channel</a>, and writing for my blog <a href="http://pctechtips.org">PCtechtips.org</a></p>
                <p>I have experience in Information Technology and Developing Web and Mobile Apps. You can contact me @ <a href="mailto:georgelouis825@gmail.com">georgelouis825@gmail.com</a></p>
                <p>This site was developed using Bootstrap framework. And all pictures are mine!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Download Section
    <section id="download" class="content-section text-center">
        <div class="download-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <h2>Download Grayscale</h2>
                    <p>You can download Grayscale for free on the preview page at Start Bootstrap.</p>
                    <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Visit Download Page</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section> -->

    <!-- Map Section -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <p>Copyright &copy; techgeorge.org 2017</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps API Key - Use your own API key to enable the map feature. More information on the Google Maps API can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/ -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRngKslUGJTlibkQ3FkfTxj3Xss1UlZDA&sensor=true"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/grayscale.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I gave an extra class to the icon and removed href

```
<a class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger scroll-down">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
</a>
```

After that i wrote this JS

```
 $(function() {
    $('.scroll-down').click (function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#myCarousel').offset().top }, 'slow');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: this is bootstrap I'm sure you should be able to add a class that's already written for this. The original template works like this I copied the html code for the img/link but doesn't work. I thought I was missing the classname. thanks anyway